# Best way to create random DateTime in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to generate a random DateTime in Ruby/Rails? Trying to create a nice seeds.rb file. Going to use it like so:

```
 Foo.create(name: Faker::Lorem.words, description: Faker::Lorem.sentence, start_date: Random.date)
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here are set of methods for generating a random integer, amount, time/datetime within a range.

```
def rand_int(from, to)
  rand_in_range(from, to).to_i
end

def rand_price(from, to)
  rand_in_range(from, to).round(2)
end

def rand_time(from, to=Time.now)
  Time.at(rand_in_range(from.to_f, to.to_f))
end

def rand_in_range(from, to)
  rand * (to - from) + from
end
```

Now you can make the following calls.

```
rand_int(60, 75)
# => 61

rand_price(10, 100)
# => 43.84

rand_time(2.days.ago)
# => Mon Mar 08 21:11:56 -0800 2010
```

Comment: getting NoMethodError: undefined method `rand_in_range' for main:Object with Ruby 2.2

Answer (score 133):

Here is how to create a date in the last 10 years:

```
rand(10.years).seconds.ago
```

You can also get a date in the future:

```
rand(10.years).seconds.from_now
```

#### Older versions of Rails (< 4.1)

Prior to Rails 4.1, there was an implicit conversion from Numeric => seconds when you call `.ago`. See [Rails PR #12389](http://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12389) for more information about this.  So this approach is possible:

```
rand(10.years).ago

rand(10.years).from_now
```

Comment: Excellent. And in case you need in past or future, you can do `rand(-5.years..5.years).ago`

Comment: My answer here uses Rails' implicit conversion from Numeric => seconds when you call `.ago`. This has been deprecated in Rails 4.1: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12389

I think I would edit my answer to be:

`rand(10.years).seconds.ago`

Comment: To address the deprecation, you could also do `rand(10).years.ago`

Comment: @MichaelSaffitz that might not work as you expect – that would give a date that is either 1 year ago, 2 years ago, 3 years ago, etc.

Comment: Updated with Rails 4.1 info.

Comment: @jeremy-moritz the edit that you made does not work - it creates a date that is exactly 1,2,3..10 years ago, not a random time between now and 10 years ago.

Comment: @MarcO'Morain, Oh i see.  i am in Rails 5, so when i use `rand(10.years).ago` in rails, i get this error `NoMethodError: undefined method \`ago' for 60641709:Integer`.  That suggestion is previous to Rails 4.1.  Perhaps we could switch the order and put the update first now that almost all rails users are in 4.1+ ?

Comment: The edit looks good to me.

Answer (score 18):

I prefer use `(1..500).to_a.rand.days.ago`

Comment: This code will throw syntax error (Range class doen't have the rand method)

Comment: And, you can use `(-200..200).to_a.rand.days.ago` to include future dates as well. Very useful for my seed data

Comment: i think this code withoud explicit typecasting looks nicer:

  `rand(-200..200).days.ago`

Comment: Marc's solution(http://stackoverflow.com/a/4886512/163203) is better. This solution creates a 500 item array every time you need to create a random date.

Comment: you can use (1..500).to_a.sample.days.ago

Answer (score 17):

You are using Faker; why not use one of the methods provided by [`Faker::Date`](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/master/doc/default/date.md)?

```
# Random date between dates
# Keyword arguments: from, to
Faker::Date.between(from: 2.days.ago, to: Date.today) #=> "Wed, 24 Sep 2014"

# Random date between dates except for certain date
# Keyword arguments: from, to, excepted
Faker::Date.between_except(from: 1.year.ago, to: 1.year.from_now, excepted: Date.today) #=> "Wed, 24 Sep 2014"

# Random date in the future (up to maximum of N days)
# Keyword arguments: days
Faker::Date.forward(days: 23) # => "Fri, 03 Oct 2014"

# Random date in the past (up to maximum of N days)
# Keyword arguments: days
Faker::Date.backward(days: 14) #=> "Fri, 19 Sep 2014"

# Random birthday date (maximum age between 18 and 65)
# Keyword arguments: min_age, max_age
Faker::Date.birthday(min_age: 18, max_age: 65) #=> "Mar, 28 Mar 1986"

# Random date in current year
Faker::Date.in_date_period #=> #<Date: 2019-09-01>

# Random date for range of year 2018 and month 2
# Keyword arguments: year, month
Faker::Date.in_date_period(year: 2018, month: 2) #=> #<Date: 2018-02-26>

# Random date for range of current year and month 2
# Keyword arguments: month
Faker::Date.in_date_period(month: 2) #=> #<Date: 2019-02-26>
```

*current Faker version: 2.11.0*

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to create a date in this month:

```
day = 1.times.map{ 0+Random.rand(30) }.join.to_i  
rand(day.days).ago
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using [DateTime's `advance`](http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/advance)

```
def rand_date
  # return a random date within 100 days of today in both past and future directions.
  n = rand(-100..100)
  Date.today.advance(days: n)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use:

```
# get random DateTime in last 3 weeks
DateTime.now - (rand * 21)
```

Answer (score 1):

other way:

```
(10..20).to_a.sample.years.ago
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself but you could create a random integer between two dates using the number of seconds since epoch.  For example, to get a random date for the last week.

```
end = Time.now
start = (end - 1.week).to_i
random_date = Time.at(rand(end.to_i - start)) + start
```

Of course you end up with a Time object instead of a DateTime but I'm sure you can covert from here.

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in another question I think the following code-snippet is more consisent regarding the data-types of the parameters and of the value to be returned. [Stackoverflow: How to generate a random date in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894198/how-to-generate-a-random-date-in-ruby/12038349#12038349)

Anyway this uses the rand() method's internal logic what is the random Date or random Time within a span. Maybe someone has a more efficient way to set the default-parameter **to** (Time.now.to_date) of the method **random_date**, so it doesn't need this typecasting.

```
def random_time from = Time.at(0.0), to = Time.now
  rand(from..to)
end

# works quite similar to date :)
def random_date from = Date.new(1970), to = Time.now.to_date
  rand(from..to)
end
```

Edit: this code won't work before ruby v1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Time Range to `rand`

```
rand(10.weeks.ago..1.day.ago)
```

Output Example:

```
=> Fri, 10 Jan 2020 10:28:52 WIB +07:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Without user faker (cause I'm using an old version of ruby):

```
Time.zone.now - rand(16..35.years) - rand(1..31).days
```

Answer (score -1):

My 'ish' gem provides a nice way of handling this:

```
# plus/minus 5 min of input date
Time.now.ish
# override that time range like this
Time.now.ish(:offset => 1.year)
```

https://github.com/spilliton/ish