# How to generate a random date in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date, random

I have a model in my Rails 3 application which has a `date` field:

```
class CreateJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :jobs do |t|
      t.date "job_date", :null => false
      ...
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

I would like to prepopulate my database with random date values.

What is the easiest way to generate a random date ?

Comment: can't you just do Time.now? Or do you really need to use random dates?

Comment: I really want to have random values :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Here's a slight expansion on Chris' answer, with optional `from` and `to` parameters:

```
def time_rand from = 0.0, to = Time.now
  Time.at(from + rand * (to.to_f - from.to_f))
end

> time_rand
 => 1977-11-02 04:42:02 0100 
> time_rand Time.local(2010, 1, 1)
 => 2010-07-17 00:22:42 0200 
> time_rand Time.local(2010, 1, 1), Time.local(2010, 7, 1)
 => 2010-06-28 06:44:27 0200
```

Comment: It works. Just wondering could it be simplified with `Time.at(rand * Time.now.to_f)`?

Comment: I keep wondering when this will become part of ruby core! Like `rand(date1..date2)`!

Comment: Btw, there's a bug in JRuby right now, so I had to use an extra .to_time before sending to Time.at--in order to get it to work in JRuby 1.7.4--like this: ```Time.at((from + rand * (to.to_f - from.to_f)).to_time)```

Comment: This is returning a Time, not a Date. to return a date, just add "to_date" at the end.  (Comparisons between Date and Time will send you an error in rails)

Comment: @VarunVohra Shit this is actually already core for me on Rails 5 / Ruby 2.3 (not sure from which it is coming from)

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris This was around rails 3.x and ruby 1.9.x if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 46):

Generate a random time between epoch, the beginning of 1970, and now:

```
Time.at(rand * Time.now.to_i)
```

Answer (score 24):

Keeping simple..

```
Date.today-rand(10000) #for previous dates

Date.today+rand(10000) #for future dates
```

PS. Increasing/Decreasing the '10000' parameter, changes the range of dates available.

Answer (score 17):

```
rand(Date.civil(1990, 1, 1)..Date.civil(2050, 12, 31))
```

my favorite method

```
def random_date_in_year(year)
  return rand(Date.civil(year.min, 1, 1)..Date.civil(year.max, 12, 31)) if year.kind_of?(Range)
  rand(Date.civil(year, 1, 1)..Date.civil(year, 12, 31))
end
```

then use like

```
random_date = random_date_in_year(2000..2020)
```

Answer (score 7):

For recent versions of Ruby/Rails, You can use `rand` on a `Time` range ❤️ !!

```
min_date = Time.now - 8.years
max_date = Time.now - 1.year
rand(min_date..max_date)
# => "2009-12-21T15:15:17.162+01:00" (Time)
```

Feel free to add `to_date`, `to_datetime`, etc. to convert to your favourite class

Tested on Rails 5.0.3 and Ruby 2.3.3, but apparently available from Ruby 1.9+ and Rails 3+

Answer (score 7):

The prettiest solution to me is:

```
rand(1.year.ago..50.weeks.from_now).to_date
```

Answer (score 4):

The following returns a random date-time in the past 3 weeks in Ruby (sans Rails).

`DateTime.now - (rand * 21)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's also a more (in my oppinion) improved version of Mladen's code-snippet. Luckily Ruby's *rand()* function can also handle Time-Objects. Regarding the Date-Object is defined when including Rails, the rand() method gets overwritten so it can handle also Date-Objects. e.g.:

```
# works even with basic ruby
def random_time from = Time.at(0.0), to = Time.now
  rand(from..to)
end

# works only with rails. syntax is quite similar to time method above :)
def random_date from = Date.new(1970), to = Time.now.to_date
  rand(from..to)
end
```

Edit: this code won't work before ruby v1.9.3

Answer (score 2):

Here's my one liner to generate a random date in the last 30 days (for example):

```
Time.now - (0..30).to_a.sample.days - (0..24).to_a.sample.hours
```

Works great for my lorem ipsum. Obviously minutes and seconds would be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Rails, you can install the `faker` gem and make use of the [Faker::Date](https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/doc/v1.9.1/date.md) module.

e.g. The following generates a random date in the year of 2018:

`Faker::Date.between(Date.parse('01/01/2018'), Date.parse('31/12/2018'))`

Answer (score 0):

Mladen's answer is a little difficult to understand from just a single look. Here's my take on this.

```
def time_rand from=0, to= Time.now
  Time.at(rand(from.to_i..to.to_i))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Given 2 dates, it will return a random date between the given ones:

```
Time.at(rand(start_date.to_time..end_date.to_time)).to_date
# => Mon, 29 Apr 2019
```