# Ruby find next Thursday (or any day of the week)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

What is the best way to calculate the Date, Month, and Year of the next Thursday (or any day) from today in Ruby?

**UPDATE** In order to create dummy objects, I'm trying to figure out how to calculate a random time. In all, I'd like to produce a random time between 5 and 10 PM on the next Thursday of the week.

Comment: You know, this question was older than the one it is marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: If you find this question on Google and you're using Rails > 5 then use `Date.today.next_occurring(:friday)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<strike>`DateTime.now.next_week.next_day(3)`</strike>

As @Nils Riedemann pointed out:

> Keep in mind that it will not get the next thursday, but the thursday
>   of the next week. eg. If tomorrow was thursday, it won't return
>   tomorrow, but next week's thursdays.

Here is an excerpt of some code I've written recently which handles the missing case.

```
require 'date'

module DateTimeMixin

  def next_week
    self + (7 - self.wday)
  end

  def next_wday (n)
    n > self.wday ? self + (n - self.wday) : self.next_week.next_day(n)
  end

end

# Example

ruby-1.9.3-p194 :001 > x = DateTime.now.extend(DateTimeMixin)
 => #<DateTime: 2012-10-19T15:46:57-05:00 ... > 

ruby-1.9.3-p194 :002 > x.next_week
 => #<DateTime: 2012-10-21T15:46:57-05:00 ... > 

ruby-1.9.3-p194 :003 > x.next_wday(4)
 => #<DateTime: 2012-10-25T15:46:57-05:00 ... >
```

Comment: cool, I like this solution - I've posted a follow up question.

Comment: Moving the goal posts like this is discouraged. If you wanted to know something initially, put it in your question.

Comment: its ok, i figured it out with help from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410639/best-way-to-create-random-datetime-in-rails thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that it will not get the next thursday, but the thursday of the next week. eg. If tomorrow was thursday, it won't return tomorrow, but next week's thursdays.

Answer (score 40):

```
date = Date.today
date += 1 + ((3-date.wday) % 7)
# date is now next Thursday
```

Comment: Crouching tiger, hidden dragon, this is probably the best answer on this thread. :D Thanks

Comment: @Trip Hey, you even inspired me to make it simpler just now :)

Comment: That returns the same date ;)

Comment: @Trip Yeah, but it avoids needlessly making `Date` objects in a loop.

Comment: It doesn't return the next Thursday, it returns, `date`. It's incorrect.

Comment: @Trip I'm getting this result, which seems right: http://ideone.com/kbfMU. I'm on Ruby 1.9, maybe something changed since 1.8 if you're using that.

Comment: In Ruby 1.9 it adds seconds. Multiply it with `60*60*24`.

Comment: @Karoly The docs don't mention any difference between [`Date#+` in 1.8](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2B) and [in 1.9](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2B). Can you produce some sort of test case that shows my error?

Comment: sorry, could it be that I did it with Time? I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: This is returning current date if Date.today is already Thursday. I would suggest `date += ((4 - date.wday) % 7) == 0 ? 7 : (4 - date.wday)`

Comment: @kode Oh, that's what the problem was. Luckily it's fixable while still preserving the golfiness of the answer :)

Answer (score 21):

Aside from getting next Thursday as the others described, Ruby provides easy methods to get the month and year from any date:

```
month = date.month
year = date.year
```

Inside of Rails you can easily get next Thursday as such:

```
next_thur = Date.today.next_week.advance(:days=>3)
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @IvanSelivanov in the comments for pointing this out. You can skip a step by doing:

```
next_thur = Date.today.next_week(:thursday)
```

Comment: What a great! `next_week` always make the date next week Monday. So we can use it tricky.

Comment: Awesome!!! Very useful.

Comment: You can also get the following Thursday (same week or next) using the following: `week_start = Date.current.wday > 4 ? Date.current.next_week :  Date.current.beginning_of_week
week_start.advance(days: 3)`

Comment: @DavidBattersby you should put your comment as an answer to the question, not as a comment

Comment: @WattsInABox question appears to be closed to new answers. The accepted answer is too verbose IMO. No other answer on this page was a perfect fit for my use case hence adding it here for any future visitors.

Comment: David, I'm trying to get that fixed since someone reported that this isn't actually the duplicate. Thanks for posting your response

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, IMO.

Comment: could be simpler: `Date.today.next_week(:thursday)`

Answer (score 13):

IMO the [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/) library is awesome for stuff like this.

The Ruby code would be:

```
def date_of_next(day)
    Chronic.parse('next #{day}')
end
```

Comment: that's a serious overkill

Comment: @PiotrekOkoński Yep. But usually when there's one need for this functionality in an app there are more.

Comment: 5 years since this answer posted, I feel [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) library is good but it is not actively maintained now. If chronic returns erroneous dates then we will be screwed. That's why i am scared of using it because in my application,  calculation with dates are very cruicial.  Certainly, there is a lot of demand in this date calculation/parsing domain.

Comment: If only there was some way we could modify its source code.

Comment: thanks for the recommandation, amazing library

Answer (score 4):

This SO answer is also short and simple
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7930553/3766839

```
def date_of_next(day)
  date  = Date.parse(day)
  delta = date > Date.today ? 0 : 7
  date + delta
end

date_of_next "Thursday"
```