# Ruby code to get the date of next Monday (or any day of the week)

Tags: ruby, date

Given an input of, for example,

```
day = 'Monday'
```

how can I calculate the date of the next `day`?

```
def date_of_next(day)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
require 'date'

def date_of_next(day)
  date  = Date.parse(day)
  delta = date > Date.today ? 0 : 7
  date + delta
end

Date.today
#=>#<Date: 2011-10-28 (4911725/2,0,2299161)>
date_of_next "Monday"
#=>#<Date: 2011-10-31 (4911731/2,0,2299161)>
date_of_next "Sunday"
#=>#<Date: 2011-10-30 (4911729/2,0,2299161)>
```

Comment: `Date.parse(day)` awesome trick... before this answer I didn't know.. +1

Answer (score 52):

For anyone like me who came here looking for a solution in Rails to this problem, as of Rails 5.2 there is a much easier method to do this.

For anyone (like the original poster) not specifically using Rails, this functionality is available in the [ActiveSupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/versions/5.2.0) gem.

To find the next occurring day of a week, we can simply write something like `Date.today.next_occurring(:friday)`.

See [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-next_occurring) for more details.

Answer (score 24):

I know this is an old post, but I came up with a couple of methods to quickly get the previous and next day of the week.

```
# date is a Date object and day_of_week is 0 to 6 for Sunday to Saturday

require 'Date'

def get_next_day(date, day_of_week)
  date + ((day_of_week - date.wday) % 7)
end

def get_previous_day(date, day_of_week)
  date - ((date.wday - day_of_week) % 7)
end

puts today = Date.today
# 2015-02-24

puts next_friday = get_next_day(today, 5)
# 2015-02-27

puts last_friday = get_previous_day(today, 5)
# 2015-02-20
```

Comment: in your example you used "5" as the day of the week, but wrote monday as the variable name. I think you meant to use "friday"

Comment: @PETER: Thanks for catching that

Comment: If it's currently Monday, won't `get_next_day(date, 1)` return the current date?

Comment: @MiloP Yes it will. That was the desired behavior for my project. The name of the functions are a little misleading.

Answer (score 18):

**Rails >= 5.2.3**

```
Date.current.next_occurring(:monday)
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-next_occurring

Answer (score 14):

For stuff like this I rely on the [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/) library.

The Ruby code would be:

```
def date_of_next(day)
    Chronic.parse("next #{day}")
end
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are using rails you can use `Date.today.sunday` for Sunday or `Date.today.monday` for Monday. And then `Date.today.sunday - 1.day` for Saturday etc.

Comment: `Date.today` is only available if you are using Rails or have included ActiveSupport. Even then `Date.today.monday` gives `undefined method`

Comment: This actually works for me. `irb(main):001:0> Date.today.monday
=> Mon, 17 Aug 2015`

Comment: `Date.today.monday` should work, but such a method only exists for `#monday`, not the other days of the week.   http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/DateAndTime/Calculations#monday-instance_method

Comment: Keep an eye, this approach doesn't returns you the _next_ monday, but the monday for _this_ week

Answer (score 5):

A Rails 4-compatible solution:

`(Date.today + 1.week).beginning_of_week(:monday)`

where you can provide the day you'd like to find as a symbol argument; the default is `:monday`.

Note that this will find the **next** occurrence of the given day - if today is Monday and you're looking for the next Monday, it will return the Monday one week from today.

Some equivalent ways to do it:

`1.week.from_now.beginning_of_week(:monday).to_date`

`1.week.since(Date.today).beginning_of_week(:monday)`

(source: https://apidock.com/rails/Date/beginning_of_week/class)

Comment: or `1.week.from_now.beginning_of_week(:monday)`

Comment: @stephan.com That would return a `TimeWithZone`, while the OP is looking for a date. `1.week.from_now.beginning_of_week(:monday).to_date` would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a Ruby question, but I think many people using Rails are gonna find this. Many answers use `Date.today`, which is server time and is usually not a good idea to use if you're on Rails. Recommended to incorporate user's time zone:

```
DateTime.now.in_time_zone(my_user.time_zone).next_occurring(:monday)
```