# Finding which date comes first of the next week - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

I need to define which comes first before I run the def. I have to rake a file and set the date for the coming week BUT that date could be either Monday or Wednesday. I've gotten it thus far but not sure how to judge which date to use in this. I need to use whatever date comes first.

```
require 'date'

def date_of_next(day1, day2)
  day = day1
  date  = Date.parse(day)
  delta = date >= Date.today ? 0 : 7
  date + delta
end

hello = date_of_next("Monday", "Wednesday")
puts hello
```

The Problem: If I am on Saturday, I need to get the date for the coming "Monday". But, if I am on Tuesday, I need to get the date of "Wednesday". When I have the task finalized, it will run daily getting this information.

Comment: Even though the question has been answered, for the benefit of future readers, I think the question needs to be clarified. My understanding is this: Weeks begin on Sunday. Day-of-week `day1` precedes `day2` (e.g., `day1` = 'Monday', day2 = `Wednesday`). Return `day1`'s date if today's date is no later than `day1`'s date. Else return `day2`'s date if today's date is no later than `day2`'s date. Else return `day1`'s date in the following week. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/7930553/477037:

```
def date_of_next(day)
  date  = Date.parse(day)
  delta = date > Date.today ? 0 : 7
  date + delta
end
```

The above method returns the date for a single day. To find the first date for multiple days, call it for each day and find the first one (by sorting the dates):

```
def first_date_of_next(*days)
  days.map { |day| date_of_next(day) }.sort.first
end

first_date_of_next("Monday", "Wednesday")
#=> #<Date: 2013-10-16 ((2456582j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly and yes, that is where the code was brought from. Thanks so much for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Would this meet your requirements?

```
require 'Date'
def date_of_next(early_dow, late_dow)
  early_date = Date.parse(early_dow)
  late_date = Date.parse(late_dow)
  today = Date.today
  if today <= early_date
    early_date
  elsif today <= late_date
    late_date
  else
    early_date + 7
  end
end
```

Comment: How do I define that it could be either "Monday" or "Wednesday" though?

Comment: Just call `date_of_next('Monday')` or `date_of_next('Monday')`.

Comment: But I need to figure out which day comes first related to the day that I am on. It could be Monday but it could also be Wednesday. How do I pass that variable if it is dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'date'

def date_of_next(d)
  Date.today.step(Date.today + 7).select{ |i| puts i if i.strftime("%A") == "#{d}" && i > Date.today} 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
require 'Date'

def date_of_next(*day_names)
  weekdays = day_names.map{|dayname| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day_name) }
  Range.new(Date.today, Date.today+6).detect{|day| weekdays.include? day.wday }
end
```

Here we're globbing the input allowing you to detect one or more weekday names.  The first line finds the index of the name of the weekday in the Date::DAYNAMES array.  In the second line we process up to a week's worth of dates returning when the first day.wday (weekday index) matches one of the weekdays we're looking for.