# Ruby how can i get date of Monday after a given date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

Given A Day i-e Monday and a Date e.g: Sat, 09 Aug 2014

how can i get the date of Monday coming immediately after given Date

**Update:**

```
def get_date_after(date, day)
    return date if date.wday == day.to_date.wday
    days_difference = (date - day.to_date).to_i
    result = day.to_date + days_difference + (day.to_date.wday - date.wday)
    result = result + 1.week if result.to_date < date
end
```

I was looking for something like above method, calling it would return the date of the **day** passed coming immediately after the **date** passed

```
get_date_after(DateTime.parse("15/09/2014").to_date, "Wednesday") #=> 17/09/2014
```

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930370/ruby-code-to-get-the-date-of-next-monday-or-any-day-of-the-week

Comment: @Rahu1 i don't need the date of next Monday, what i am looking for is date of Monday immediately after a given date

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, and shouldn't have been closed as one. However, it is a poor-quality question that doesn't include any research effort or code. You can improve your question by updating it with what you've tried, why it doesn't work, and why other related questions don't solve your issue. After that, flag to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `chronic` gem allows you to parse date expressions, e.g. `Chronic.parse("next Monday")`. You can add a reference date with the `now` option. Here's how it could be used for your method:

```
def get_date_after(date, day)
  Chronic.parse("next #{day}", now: date)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In rails you can do it this way 
`Date.today.next_week(day = :monday)`

Comment: If today is Friday and the wants the next Saturday he'll get the wrong one though.

Comment: I want Monday after a given date, like if I provide today's date method should return July 14, 2014, which is immediate Monday's date

Comment: You can use this line for testing Chronic's method with RSpec