# How to get day of the week next week?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried something like...

```
<%= Date.current.next_week.monday %>
<%= Date.current.next_week.tuesday %>
<%= Date.current.next_week.wednesday %>
<%= Date.current.next_week.thursday %>
<%= Date.current.next_week.friday %>
```

Getting error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'tuesday' for Mon, 17 Apr 2017:Date):`

So as of today's date the dates would be...

```
Apr 17
Apr 18
Apr 19
Apr 20
Apr 21
```

--

Not duplicate (I don't think). I tried those answers. I was unable to render the appropriate days in the view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby code to get the date of next Monday (or any day of the week)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930370/ruby-code-to-get-the-date-of-next-monday-or-any-day-of-the-week)

Comment: I tried those answers. I was unable to render the appropriate days in the view @radubogdan

Comment: Ok :) Looks like there is a good answer suitable for your question. Cheers

Comment: @radubogdan: It is not a duplicate. The linked answer gives you the next thursday (tomorrow), not thursday of next week (in 8 days).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax for [`next_week`](https://apidock.com/rails/DateAndTime/Calculations/next_week) needs tweaking:

```
# Works
<%= Date.current.next_week(:tuesday) %>
```

To understand why your original approach doesn't work: `monday` and `sunday` just happen to be defined on [DateAndTime::Calculations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html), but the other days of the week are not.

Comment: Alternatively `Date.current.next_week + n` if you prefer a numerical offset.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever need it in plain Ruby, here's a simple way to get it:

- `date` minus [`cwday`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-cwday) (day of calendar week) gives you "last sunday"
- "Last sunday + 8" gives you "next monday".

---

```
require 'date'

def next_week(date, day = :monday)
  days = %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)
  date - date.cwday + 8 + days.index(day.to_s.downcase).to_i
end

puts next_week(Date.today)
# 2017-04-17
puts next_week(Date.today, :friday)
# 2017-04-21
puts next_week(Date.new(2017,4,16))
# 2017-04-17
puts next_week(Date.new(2017,4,17))
# 2017-04-24
```

For your question, you could use:

```
next_monday = next_week(Date.today)
puts working_days_next_week = Array.new(5){ |i| next_monday + i }
# 2017-04-17
# 2017-04-18
# 2017-04-19
# 2017-04-20
# 2017-04-21
```