# Get the first occurrence of a specific day after a given date

Tags: ruby

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930370/ruby-code-to-get-the-date-of-next-monday-or-any-day-of-the-week) provides an answer to find the first occurrence of a day (e.g. Thursday) after today's date.

I would like to get a more general function which gives the first occurrence of a day (e.g. Thursday) after any given date (e.g. November 1st, 2017).

The method would therefore take 2 arguments: the Date (either as a String, or as a Date object) and the day (as a String).

One way I found is to check each day after with the `thursday?` method (e.g. `my_date_object.thursday?`) but you would need a switch / if-else statement to check which day to check against, which makes the method rather bulky, as seen below.

```
def get_next_day_after_date(date, day)
  days_in_week = 7
  week = []
  days_in_week.times { |day_after| week << (date + day_after) }
  if day.casecmp('Monday').zero?
    week.select(&:monday?)
  elsif day.casecmp('Tuesday').zero?
    week.select(&:tuesday?)
  elsif day.casecmp('Wednesday').zero?
    week.select(&:wednesday?)
  # same code for Thursday to Sunday
  end
end
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this in pure Ruby? (no use of `active_support` or rails-specific methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require "date"

def get_next_day_after_day(date, day)
  date + (Date.strptime(day, "%A") - date) % 7
end
```

Comment: Works well, thanks. For anyone planning to use this, be aware that the behavior of this function should be used with `Date` object only as the method will behave differently with `DateTime` objects. For example, calling this on a `DateTime` object representing `Friday 24 November 2017 00:00` will return a date object representing `24 November 2017` but calling the same method on a `DateTime` object set to `Friday 24 November 2017 15:00` will return a date object set to `1 December 2017`.

Comment: To make it safe to use with `DateTime` object, the method can be edited as follows: `date + (Date.strptime(day, '%A') - date.to_date) % 7`