# Generating a random date without time in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I have a date of birth column on my user table that takes a `DATE`. As this datatype appears as `YYYY-MM-DD`, I assume that when inputting a date to the database it must have the format, for example: `2013-12-26`.

I have seen methods on StackOverflow for creating a random DateTime in Ruby, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410639/best-way-to-create-random-datetime-in-rails). However, after much searching I can't find a way to generate a random date without the time, for example in the past 100 years, and have it properly formatted for the `DATE` datatype. In Rails, what is the best way to generate a random date **without the time?**

This seems to work:

```
    def rand_date(days)
      date = Date.today-rand(days)
      date.to_s(:db)
    end
```

But is there a more elegant solution that comes with Rails? I am new to Rails and programming, so any assistance would be most helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is correct. If you are using Rails, there are some trivial improvements such as

```
def rand_date(days)
  rand(days).days.ago(Date.today)
end
```

which is mostly equivalent to

```
def rand_date(days)
  rand(days).days.ago.to_date
end
```

The second version is less efficient because it creates more Date/Time objects during the internal conversions.

Apply `to_s(:db)` if you need the Date to be formatted as String.

A different approach would require you to construct a date passing the result of a `rand` to `Date.new`.

Answer (score 2):

This is in core `ruby`:

```
  1 #!usr/bin/ruby
  2 
  3 require 'date'.
  4 
  5 10.times do |t|
  6 random_year = Random.new.rand(2000..2014) # custom range for years
  7 random_month =Random.new.rand(1..12)
  8 random_day  = Random.new.rand(1..30)
  9 puts "#{Date.new(random_year,random_month,random_day)}"
 10 end

2014-11-29
2010-10-20
2006-02-23
2009-09-17
2006-01-14
2009-01-06
2002-07-06
2005-11-05
2013-06-20
2005-12-02
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I used to generate random birth dates when populating a customer database. It works on days, and in this example, gives random dates between 1967-01-09 and 1993-01-12 by using the `Date#jd` method:

```
Date.jd(2439500 + rand(9500))
```

You can twiddle the dates generated by setting the base (in this case 2439500, which is 1967-01-09) and the random number to increase or decrease the range of dates produced.

Example:

```
irb(main):043:0> 10.times { puts Date.jd(2439500 + rand(9500)) }
1973-06-07
1973-11-09
1983-07-27
1990-11-03
1967-06-18
1967-06-20
1970-07-28
1990-05-13
1986-11-26
1989-02-15
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!